# the django-debug-tool lead to an redirect-loop on admin site?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-debug-toolbar, redirect-loop

> 302 FOUND
>
> Location: /admin/
>
> The Django Debug Toolbar has intercepted a redirect to the above URL for debug viewing purposes. You can click the above link to continue with the redirect as normal.

the loop is between `/admin` and `/admin/login/?next=/admin/`

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. The strange thing is that the site is on a virtual machine that I have built and rebuilt with code that works for coworkers (and myself, until this morning.)

Comment: Deleted cookies for localhost (where I was accessing the site). Made a different user. Neither of these changed the behavior.

Comment: Further testing seems to indicate that it's a model issue, although we are getting no clues in any logs at all as to why this loop is occurring.

Comment: Could you add your settings file, please?

Answer (score 3):

In the situation I encountered this problem, it turned out that a magic settings import improperly set the SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN setting. After we corrected this setting, the problem was solved.

We were lead to the solution after reading the following account:

https://www.reddit.com/r/django/comments/2knwo8/migrating_from_heroku_to_digital_ocean_nginx_post/

Answer (score -1):

I used a solution and my problem was solved
I deleted the cookies for the hosting address of the Django server (in the corresponding browser like Chrome)
Once I restarted the server, the problem was resolved and I no longer had to redirect

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).